# Unit testing http get method in component

Tags: unit-testing, angular5

I am new to testing and angular 5.
I have a component function which in turn calls the http get method and retuns json data.
I would like to test it.
this is my component function snippet

```
this.enablebutton=false;
this.users=[];
getUsers(){
   this.http.get(url).subscribe(result=>{this.users=result

     if(this.users.length>0){
      this.enablebutton=true;
    }
   })
}
```

on tutorials I find they have a seperate service layer for calling the web services to fetch data like this and for which we have test cases,but I am not using any services currently.

```
 this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(result=> this.users= result);
```

I wrote my test case as

```
beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  //  spyOn(component, "getUsers").and.callThrough();
      component.getUsers();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

I dont know how to set the values for result from http.get call manually and test the conditions for this.enablebutton which relies on the result from the http call.
Thank you.

Comment: First step: indent your code properly, to make it readable. Second step: don't spy on the method you want to test: that makes no sense, since it replaces the method you want to test by a method doing nothing. Third step: read https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests to understand how to mock Http.

Comment: how to use mock http directly on http.get method.

Comment: You can also do that, by spying on http.get. https://jasmine.github.io/2.8/introduction#section-Spies. Read the documentation, and try something. If you're stuck, tell precisely what you tried and what problem you faced.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet your comment was very useful ,my blocker is removed and I can start my testing :)